# How to get the clicked cell inside the click event handler of a table row?

Tags: jquery

There is a html table populated dynamically from an ajax , on which there is a click handler on the tr element :

```
$("#table").on("click" ,"tr", function() {
   // working codes
}
```

I want to get the corresponding clicked cell inside the above code. How to do that ?

Comment: Try $(this). $(this) will be "tr"

Comment: I want the td , not tr !!!!!

Comment: Why don't you just delegate to `td` instead of `tr`?

Comment: Oh sorry $(this)..children() or you can find $(this).find( "td" )

Comment: @ArthurQocharyan That will return all the cells, not just the clicked cells.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right .

Answer (score 1):

Delegate to `td` instead of `tr`. Then `this` will be the clicked cell.

```
$("#table").on("click" ,"td", function() {
   console.log($(this).text());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. What is the above code, and why shouldn't it be called?

Comment: You're supposed to use this code **instead** of the code in the post, so you should delete that code.

Comment: but there are statements I must do about the tr !

Comment: Then what's wrong? Do the things that need the cell in the `td` handler, and do the things that only need the row in the `tr` handler.